# Indian spouse of a British Citizen (UK Passport holder) need visa to enter Spain?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, schengen-visas, spain

My wife is a Indian passport holder who has "indefinite leave to remain" stamp on her passport which allows her to stay in the UK being my spouse. I believe she still does need a Visa to enter the EU Country (Spain in my case), but it would be free of charge? My spouse will be travelling with me and I will be carrying her cost of being in Spain.

I have a couple of questions if someone could please help me with them:

1. Would the visa be free for my Spouse? If it's free, is there any other charge (e.g. visa application fee, or visa centre fee to process the application)
2. How long is the application process? Could I get the visa within a month if I apply now?
3. I'd prefer doing the Visa myself rather than go through an agency, so would I have to go to London to submit my application or is there any other way of submitting the application?
4. What documents would I need to show that she is my wife? E.g. Marriage certificate etc?
5. Do I need it in writing that I accept that my spouse will be travelling with me and I will pay for everything on her behalf?
6. Is there anywhere closer I could submit the application rather than go till London? (I'm based in Leicester)

Any other information about applying for the Visa would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)